# multiply a value by a multiplication rating?

Tags: excel, sum

I want to multiply all numbers of a column with a cotation value on the same row.

Exemple :

```
Cote          Value
1             1
5             0.5
3             0.75
```

So I want the result in B4 to be like this : =SUM(A1*B1) + SUM(A2*B2) ...

The problem is that I have 146 rows.

How can I make this more faster ?

Thanks !

Comment: You don't need SUM around those expressions. Investigate SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what SUMPRODUCT is for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A146,B2:B146)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A146)*(B1:B146))
```